# Unable to find libisl.so.15

Tags: linux, redhat, bazel

I ve been trying to install bazel on a Linux system - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7. While installing, I run into this error : (pls see link below)

[image]

As seen, it is unable to load libisl.so.15. But that shared file is indeed present on the system and it is a symbolic link. How can I make the bazel build step recognize the presence of that library file. I did search online forums for solutions but could not find any suitable one for this. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I **do not** have sudo permissions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. please insert your code in proper format, as text, and not as an image.

Comment: RHEL 7 : `bazel` will build OK with the system compiler = gcc version 4.8.5 . ... Did you set gcc to the version (5.4) in /opt/apps/ ?

Comment: @KnudLarsen..I have not set the gcc to version (5.4) ..it is the default option..I m trying to install bazel on an external server in order to compile tensorflow from source .. I do not have administrator privileges on the server and hence I m not sure if I can change the gcc version..I m contacting them to see if they can help me out here ... thanks..